# How do I know the server path for adding to an include_path

Tags: php, path, include-path

I have everything working locally with `php_value include_path "C:/wamp/www/project"` in my htaccess file, but I don't know what to set this value to once it's uploaded to the server. I tried the actual url but it didn't work; I'm guessing this needs to be relative to the server, but I'm not sure how to extrapolate the appropriate server path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the ways is to upload a test script to your server and

```
echo dirname(__file__);
```

You can see the path of the directory in which your file is.

Another way is to

```
echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']'
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

if you have "library.php" in your C:/wamp/www/project/libs you'd use

```
php_value include_path "C:/wamp/www/project/libs/"
```

and using it like

```
include("library.php");
```